# React-Native Lowest Android API level

Tags: android, react-native

I am doing some research on react-native and android. Does anyone know the lowest api level react-native supports for android? I've searched all over their docs page and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Supported operating systems are >= Android 4.1 (API 16) and >= iOS 9.0.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.56.0

Comment: It has changed to Supported operating systems are >= Android 4.1 (API 16) and >= iOS 8.0. as of 1/30/2017

Comment: Thanks for finding this. Why it's not listed on the Docs page is really irritating.

Answer (score 0):

iOS minimal version has changed to **>=8.0**, follow the link, right after the first paragraph of the readme

Answer (score 0):

In their build version from 0.38 & above i believe they have upgraded lowest supported android API to 6.0(Marshmallow) as specified on the official website

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/getting-started.html#content

They seem not to have updated the information on the GIT docs.

Comment: Where do you see this? I don't see anything in the docs about the minimum versions required now.

Comment: I did find where it says you need at least the 6.0 SDK to compile your project, but that's different than the minimum SDK version for your project. You can use the latest SDK version to compile and then ensure lower SDK support by setting the `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: Your reference link is broken!