# React Native supported platform API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I was wondering if there is any place where I can find what platform API React Native (iOS for example) support and what it does not.

I’m looking for a list preferably like that
Geolocation : supported
Calendar: Not supported 
Vibration: supported and so on..

Anything near that where I can find those information would be really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is always updated but for now its 
Basic Components includes View, Text, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, StyleSheet
User Interface includes Button, Picker, Slider, Switch
List Views includes FlatList, SectionList

There are other components specific for both IOS and Android and other components
You can check out the following link:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html

it shows the supported components and API's for both IOS and Android

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was looking for something more like canIuse with a complete comparative list thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608200/react-native-lowest-android-api-level). You may find some answers there

You can also look at this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2756) on github